# Synonyms of "hand in"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for synonyms of "hand in" which means "give something", often used in this kind of context:

> I will hand in my paper tomorrow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Stupid question, but why are you looking for a synonym? "hand in" fits very well in this sentence. (Not saying that "submit" isn't perfect, but "hand in" is just as perfect!)

Comment: A synonym that retains the "<verb> in" style is ["turn in"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/turn+in), which TFD cites as meaning "To hand in; give over: *turned in the final exam*."

Comment: @Mr Lister I want to point out that we look for a synonym since we want to have more choice of words. Don't you think that repeating the same words in a passage instead of replacing them with synonyms makes it monotonous and odd?

Comment: @Peter That depends entirely on the passage. If you have a sentence like "First I handed in my paper, then he handed in his" and you change one of the hands to "submit", then you will leave the reader wondering if you mean something else with "submit" than with "hand in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Submit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/submit)" seems perfect:

> to present or propose to another for review, consideration, or
>   decision; also:  to deliver formally (*submitted* my resignation)

It is commonly used in your example context: "I will submit my paper tomorrow."

There is also "[tender](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tender?show=0&t=1393334790)", though it is used more formally:

> to present for acceptance:  offer (*tendered* my resignation)

It would generally not be used for the specific example context you have given, but is suitable for others.

Answer (score 1):

A good synonym would be submit.